# Кракозябры в консоли линукс

Tags: linux, шрифты, консоль, fedora

Не было проблемы лет пять. Но при переустановке *Федоры* с нуля всплила опять.

Итак, в консоли (*не терминале*) (Ctrl-Alt-F3, например) линукс выводились квадратики. `setfont` коим образом я фиксил это раньше не срабатывал, выводил ошибку

```
couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

Читая FAQ по Федоре нашел, что нужно установить некоторые шрифты и прописать
в vconsole.conf

```
KEYMAP="us"
FONT="ter-v16n"
```

Не сработало. Потом пересобрал `sudo dracut ---force`
Вместо квадратиков появились кракозябры. Если выполнить команду:

```
sudo setfont ter-v16n
```

Кириллица появляется, но лишь на время. Стоит вернуться в графическую оболочку, а потом обратно — те же кракозябры.

1. Странно, что setfont без sudo вызывает ошибку и не работает. Ребята
    с чата говорят, что у них срабатывает и без рута, да и у меня рашьше
    так было.
2. Не могу понять, почему шрифт сбрасывается при переходе в другую консоль и 
    возврате назад.

---

Обновил kernel, киррилица теперь отображается корректно. Но `setfont` так же работает только из-под рута.

Comment: а зачем же вы федорой пользуетесь, это же экспериментальная версия, полно ошибок, по мне так лучше centos, да и кстати red hat иногда бесплатные аккаунты для разработчиков раздаёт

Comment: @PavelGridin наверное привык уже. Sentos вряд ли стабильнее.

Comment: centos точно стабильнее, это практически red hat, но всё конечно старое, gcc, qt всё года на два-три отстаёт

Comment: насоветуете centos в качестве рабочей станции, человек маяться будет

Comment: А что вы хотите? Там всё systemd и dbus’ом поросло, всё не так совсем как пять лет назад.